# CSS Target * classes with - and number

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this CSS which targets all classes containing a - character.

```
[class*="-"] {
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Is it possible to target all classes with a - character and a number afer it?

Comment: IMHO, if you're using CSS selectors to target all classes with a pattern, you're not using CSS correctly ;) Namely, all of those elements should share a class, which will be faster, easier to maintain, and less error-prone than pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way possible would be:

```
[class*="-0"],
[class*="-1"],
[class*="-2"],
[class*="-3"],
[class*="-4"],
[class*="-5"],
[class*="-6"],
[class*="-7"],
[class*="-8"],
[class*="-9"] {
    /*...*/
}
```

But I don't believe it's a wise selector. You should rethink your approach.